# Laravel throws error "The scheme `javascript` isn't valid. It should be either `http` or `https`"

Tags: php, node.js, laravel-5, composer-php

I just pulled out from bitbucket our Laravel company project but when I try to load the screen I get this error message:

```
The scheme `javascript` isn't valid. It should be either `http` or `https`
```

I've checked and the code is the same in production but there is works fine. It's a 5.7 version so when I run `composer install` and `npm i` I'm getting a lot of warnings can be that the cause of the error that maybe my composer and node are too updated?

This is the function on the error handler that is throws this error:

```
class InvalidArgument extends InvalidArgumentException
{
    public static function invalidScheme(string $url): self
    {
        return new static("The scheme `{$url}` isn't valid. It should be either `http` or `https`.");
    }
}
```

I've commented out all the lines from the view that may be suspicious of retrieving any js file but still getting the same error message so I guess that despite what the error log says the error may not come from the view?

Comment: Double check all your URLs.

Comment: At this time I've commented all the links ans urls on the page but I still get the same error

Comment: Please share more details. How is this error related to Composer, or to Node.js?

Comment: The code works well in production and my co-workers and we are all using the same php version. Also as the Laravel version is quite old (5.7) booth composer and node throw a lot of warnings when installing dependencies. The truth is that I am very lost I already spent two days on this.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. If the code works in production, but not on your local machines, what have you tried to check **why** this is the case? Is production using another PHP version? Another application environment? Other dependencies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a solution. The issue was caused by the composer version I was using the 2.x and after trying several previous versions finally the good one was the 1.10.

To downgrade the composer version I used the following command:

```
composer self-update --1
```

Comment: Please check your application for further bugs. Composer v1 is EOL, and by not changing to v2 you will face some problems in the future

Comment: It's high time to upgrade your app and dependencies !!

Comment: yes but it's the first time I have to do something like this and need some studying first do you know any good guide on how to do it?